How to solve an error on Puppeteer instalation using npm on Ubuntu
I'm trying to install Puppeteer (https://pptr.dev/) globally on Ubuntu 20.04:
$ sudo npm install puppeteer -g

I received this error message:
npm error code 1
npm error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/puppeteer
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node install.mjs
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-05-03T19_37_45_119Z-debug-0.log

My node version is v18.20.2
My npm version is 10.5.0
What could be causing this error?

Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, Node 20.11.1 and npm 10.2.4, but I ran without sudo: npm i -g puppeteer.

The debug log it points to should have an error message or trace.

npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer worked for me.
